# problem with POST route in nextJS and MySQL

Tags: mysql, web, next.js, routes, backend

I'm starting with NextJS (and web at all) and I'm trying to make a route to add a pokeId to a user (mysql database), but I'm encountering problems

Prisma Models:

```
model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  username String
  password String
  pokeIds PokeId[] 
}

model PokeId {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  pokeId Int
  user User @relation(fields: [pokeId], references: [id])
}
```

POST code:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    try {
        const { userId, pokeId } = await request.json();
        
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: { id: userId },
          });

        if (!user) {
            return NextResponse.json({
                success: false,
                error: "User not found",
            });
        }

        const newPokeId = await prisma.pokeId.create({
            data: {
              pokeId: pokeId,
              user: {
                connect: {
                  id: userId,
                },
              },
            },
        });


        return NextResponse.json({
            success: true,
            user,
            newPokeId
        });

    } catch (error: any) {
        return NextResponse.json({
            success: false,
            error: error.message,
        });
    }
}
```

When i try to do a POST using POSTMAN this is what a get:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": "\nInvalid `prisma.pokeId.create()` invocation:\n\n{\n  data: {\n    pokeId: 1,\n    ~~~~~~\n    user: {\n      connect: {\n        id: 1\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nUnknown argument `pokeId`. Available options are marked with ?."
}
```

I don't understand much about back-end and mysql, so any help would be very useful!!